# R - combining two data frames with missing and out of order rows

Tags: r, dataframe, addition

I have two data frames

```
merge_test_1 = t(data.frame("cats" = 1, "dogs" = 2, "horses" = 4))
merge_test_2 = t(data.frame("horses" = 1, "dogs" = 3, "rabbits" = 2))
```

They look like this:

```
       [,1]
cats      1
dogs      2
horses    4

        [,1]
horses     1
dogs       3
rabbits    2
```

Note how they don't have all row names in common, and the ones they do share are also in a different order. I would like to combine them together, so that I get something like this as a result:

```
       [,1]  [,2]
cats      1     0
dogs      2     3
horses    4     1
rabbits   0     2
```

The order in the final data frame doesn't matter so much, so long as they are combined properly. I tried using the "merge" commands but I couldn't quite figure it out.

Comment: Try to save row names as a variable in your dataframe.

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: You will need to join on something (one or multiple variables) in order to get your desired output. Here you don't have any variables apart from the values. So, you have to create one using the row names. `merge` command needs a `by=` option to merge on...

Comment: This should make it more clear https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12366946/merge-by-row-name-and-column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with the prior comments about moving the rownames to a variable, but if you'd prefer to not do this and only use base R functions, the following code should work (although the non matching cells will be `NA` instead of `0`).

```r
merge_test_1 = t(data.frame(cats = 1, dogs = 2, horses = 4))
merge_test_2 = t(data.frame(horses = 1, dogs = 3, rabbits = 2))
merge(merge_test_1, merge_test_2, by = 0, all = TRUE)
#>   Row.names V1.x V1.y
#> 1      cats    1   NA
#> 2      dogs    2    3
#> 3    horses    4    1
#> 4   rabbits   NA    2
```

Answer (score 3):

```r
library(dplyr)
merge_test_1 = t(data.frame(cats = 1, dogs = 2, horses = 4)) %>% as.data.frame()
merge_test_2 = t(data.frame(horses = 1, dogs = 3, rabbits = 2)) %>% as.data.frame()

# change row names into actual column
merge_test_1 <- tibble::rownames_to_column(merge_test_1)
merge_test_2 <- tibble::rownames_to_column(merge_test_2)

df <- full_join(merge_test_1, merge_test_2, by = "rowname")

# change NAs to 0
df[is.na(df)] <- 0

df
#>   rowname V1.x V1.y
#> 1    cats    1    0
#> 2    dogs    2    3
#> 3  horses    4    1
#> 4 rabbits    0    2
```